# LC-3 program clarification

Tags: assembly, lc3

```
.ORIG x3000

; Define variables
START   LEA R0, PROMPT ; Load the address of the prompt message
       PUTS            ; Display the prompt message
       LEA R1, INPUT   ; Load the address of the input buffer
       GETS            ; Read a string of characters from the keyboard
       AND R2, R2, #0  ; Clear R2 to use it as a counter for even numbers
       AND R3, R3, #0  ; Clear R3 to use it as a counter for odd numbers

PARSE   LDR R4, R1, #0  ; Load the first character of the input string
       ADD R1, R1, #1  ; Increment the pointer to the next character
       BRz END_PARSE   ; If R4 is zero, we have reached the end of the string

       LD R5, MINUS_48 ; Load -48 into R5
       ADD R4, R4, R5  ; Convert character to digit
       AND R5, R4, #1  ; Check if the number is odd or even
       BRz EVEN
       ADD R3, R3, #1  ; Increment the counter for odd numbers
       BRnzp CONTINUE
EVEN    ADD R2, R2, #1  ; Increment the counter for even numbers
CONTINUE BRnzp PARSE     ; Continue parsing the string

END_PARSE
       LEA R0, RESULT  ; Load the address of the result message
       PUTS            ; Display the result message

       LD R4, MINUS_48 ; Load -48 into R4
       ADD R2, R2, R4  ; Add R4 to R2 to convert the even count to a character
       OUT             ; Display the count of even numbers

       LEA R0, ODD_RESULT ; Load the address of the odd result message
       PUTS              ; Display the odd result message

       ADD R3, R3, R4    ; Add R4 to R3 to convert the odd count to a character
       OUT               ; Display the count of odd numbers

       HALT

PROMPT  .STRINGZ "Enter a string of numbers: "
INPUT   .BLKW   50
RESULT  .STRINGZ "Even numbers: "
ODD_RESULT .STRINGZ ", odd numbers: "
MINUS_48 .FILL -48    ; Define a constant for -48

.END
```

The above code is for the following prompt:

Code an Assembly Program that will:

accept a string of numbers from the user
parse the numbers and count number of odd numbers and number of even numbers
Display both counts
Submit your .asm code file along with a screenshot of your running program in the LC-3 debugger.

However when I try to run the code in LC3 Tools the console does not do what I need it to do.

---

[image: Here is the console issue for reference]

---

Before I am unable to input a string of numbers this occurs. If anyone can find why my program is not behaving how it should be according to the instructions that would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried debugging multiple times using the step out and step in tools and much more research and reading. The book I am currently learning from is, Introduction To Computing Systems: From Bits & Gates To C/C++ & Beyond, Third Edition. Chapter 5 goes over LC-3 and I have been struying that as much as possible to try and find a solution.

Comment: The original LC-3 has `PUTS` but no `GETS` — do you have a reference for your environment that supports the concept that there is a `GETS` trap?  On my environment it takes that line as a label, so does not complain..

Comment: There are other issues: while `LDR` sets the condition codes that you want for checking for the NUL terminating character in the string, the `ADD` resets the condition codes and since this is a pointer it will not become zero until it wraps around the address space.

Comment: Further, my environment complain about 50 and -48 (appearing in the data area), which should be written as #50 and #-48, respectively.

Comment: The conversion from number back to ascii digit is reverse — you add 48, not subtract 48.  If your counts go over 9 you'll have to output 2 or more ascii characters (e.g.10 is two digits, a 1 character followed by a 0 character)..

Comment: That program is counting even and odd digits in the sequence but not really parsing numbers.  You might check with instructors about whether numbers are groups of digits separated by, say, blanks/spaces, (as per normal) or they really want you to interpret each digit as its own number.

Comment: *The above code is for the following prompt:* - That terminology, of "prompt" rather than "question" or "assignment", would be typical of an AI like ChatGPT.  Did you get an AI to write this code for you, or did you write it yourself?